# Mysql database syincronizaton

Tags: mysql

I am developing a database for an organization, which has three branches. They want to use this database locally.

The problem is that they want to gather all three branches data after each three months for reporting from all of the three branches.

For example, if branch A has 40 records and branch B has 50 records and Branch C has 30 records: after three months each of the branch should have (30+40+50) records.

How can I do that? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can export individual data from 3 databases and then insert into a new database as it is not frequent (3 months interval) like **syncronize**.

**or**

You can create an API for fetching data and call the APIs in a loop, and after fetching 3 databases **separately**, join them in **one array** and then show them as you want.

It is like:

1st

1. Select Database

   2. Fetch The Data

then again

1. Change Database

   2. Fetch The Data from 2nd DB

and so on.

then join every array of data in a single variable and show it